# TradingView - pine script to exit with different total deal of Take profit and Stop Loss

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I wrote a pine script with trail exit and wanted to exit TP with 50% of the total deal for the first TP and exit SL with 100% of the total deal for the SL. then, let the trade continue and exit with the remaining total deal with the 2nd TP.
I'm currently stuck at the this stage whereby once my trade is hit the SL, it will always exit trade with 50% of the total deal which is not what I want. Can Anyone please help me on this?

[This image is not the results I want. It should be hitting SL and exit with 100% of total deal and no 2nd tp hit.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mO9fF.png)

[And from this Photo, it should be hitting the SL but it didn't exit trade also.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dd52E.png)

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/

//@version=5
strategy("Stackoverflow Question", overlay=true, process_orders_on_close = false)

showPlot            = input.bool(false, title="Show Trail Line?")

// ---------------------------
// Risk Management Functions
// ---------------------------
percentAsPoints(pcnt) =>
    strategy.position_size != 0 ? math.round(pcnt / 100.0 * strategy.position_avg_price / syminfo.mintick) : float(na)

percentAsPrice(pcnt) =>
    strategy.position_size != 0 ? ((pcnt / 100.0) + 1.0) * strategy.position_avg_price : float(na)

calcStopLossPrice(pointsOffset) =>
    strategy.position_size != 0 ? 
      strategy.position_size > 0 ? strategy.position_avg_price - pointsOffset * syminfo.mintick : 
      strategy.position_avg_price + pointsOffset * syminfo.mintick : 
      float(na)

calcProfitTrgtPrice(OffsetPts) =>
    calcStopLossPrice(-OffsetPts)

getCurrentStage(tp) =>
    var stage = 0
    // tp = strategy.position_size > 0 ? percentAsPoints(tp1) : strategy.position_size > 0 ? percentAsPoints(tp2) : 0
    tpHit = (strategy.position_size > 0  and high >= tp) or (strategy.position_size < 0 and low <= tp)
    if strategy.position_size == 0 
        stage := 0
    if stage == 0 and strategy.position_size != 0
        stage := 1
    else if stage == 1 and tpHit
        stage := 2
    stage

//change TP calculation based on needs
// ------------------------- Replacable section - Start --------------------------
var float slPrice = na
var float tpPrice = na
var float tpPrice1 = na

if strategy.position_size == 0
    slPrice := na
    tpPrice := na
    tpPrice1 := na 

longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28)) and strategy.position_size == 0
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    slPrice := close * 0.98
    tpPrice := close * 1.02
    tpPrice1 := close * 1.04
    

shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28)) and strategy.position_size == 0
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
    slPrice := close * 1.02
    tpPrice := close * 0.98
    tpPrice1 := close * 0.96

float stopLevel = na
float trailOffsetLevel = na
float profitLevel = tpPrice1
int curStage = na
// based on current stage set up exit
// note: we use same exit ids ("x") consciously, for MODIFY the exit's parameters
curStage := getCurrentStage(tpPrice)
if curStage == 1
    stopLevel := slPrice
    strategy.exit("TP", "Long", qty= 0.5 * strategy.position_size, limit = tpPrice, comment_profit = "Long TP")
    strategy.exit("TP", "Short", qty= 0.5 * strategy.position_size, limit = tpPrice, comment_profit = "Short TP")

    strategy.exit("SL", "Long", qty = strategy.position_size, stop = slPrice, comment_loss = "Long SL")
    strategy.exit("SL", "Short", qty = strategy.position_size, stop = slPrice, comment_loss = "Short SL")

else if curStage == 2
    stopLevel := strategy.position_avg_price
    strategy.exit("TP", "Long", stop = stopLevel, limit = tpPrice1, comment_profit = "Long TP", comment_loss = "Break Even")
    strategy.exit("TP", "Short", stop = stopLevel, limit = tpPrice1, comment_profit = "Short TP", comment_loss = "Break Even")
else
    strategy.cancel("TP")

text1 = str.tostring(strategy.closedtrades.exit_id(strategy.closedtrades - 1))
plot(showPlot ? stopLevel : na, style = plot.style_linebr, color = color.red, title="SL Line")
plot(showPlot ? profitLevel : na, style = plot.style_linebr, color = color.blue, title="TP 2 Line")
plot(showPlot ? tpPrice : na, style = plot.style_linebr, color = color.white, title="TP Line")
plotchar(curStage, "curStage", "")
plotchar(strategy.position_size, "strategy.position_size", "")
var testTable = table.new(position.top_right, 1, 5, color.orange, border_width = 1)

if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory or barstate.isrealtime
    table.cell(testTable, 0, 0, 'Last closed trade:')
    table.cell(testTable, 0, 1, "Order stop price value: " + strategy.closedtrades.entry_comment(strategy.closedtrades - 1))
    table.cell(testTable, 0, 2, "Actual Entry Price: " + str.tostring(strategy.closedtrades.entry_price(strategy.closedtrades - 1)))
    table.cell(testTable, 0, 3, "Exit Id: " + strategy.closedtrades.exit_id(strategy.closedtrades - 1))
    table.cell(testTable, 0, 4, "Exit Comment: " + str.tostring(strategy.closedtrades.exit_comment(strategy.closedtrades - 1)))
```

Here is the updated code and photo after retry.

```
curStage := getCurrentStage(tpPrice)
if curStage == 1
    stopLevel := slPrice
    strategy.exit("TP L", "Long", qty_percent = 50, limit = tpPrice, comment_profit = "Long TP")
    strategy.exit("TP S", "Short", qty_percent = 50, limit = tpPrice, comment_profit = "Short TP")

    strategy.exit("SL L", "Long", qty_percent = 100, stop = slPrice, comment_loss = "Long SL")
    strategy.exit("SL S", "Short", qty_percent = 100, stop = slPrice, comment_loss = "Short SL")

else if curStage == 2
    stopLevel := strategy.position_avg_price
    strategy.exit("TP L2", "Long", qty = strategy.position_size, stop = stopLevel, limit = tpPrice1, comment_profit = "Long TP", comment_loss = "Break Even")
    strategy.exit("TP  S2", "Short", qty = strategy.position_size, stop = stopLevel, limit = tpPrice1, comment_profit = "Short TP", comment_loss = "Break Even")

    strategy.cancel("TP L")
    strategy.cancel("TP S")
    strategy.cancel("SL L")
    strategy.cancel("SL S")
```

[The photo is after retry, the SL is still incorrect as it was not exit with 1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxzSU.png)
here is my attached source code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you have two exit orders with the same id, the second one will modify the first one.

What you need to do is, have your `strategy.exit()`s with different ids. Those should combine TP and SL. And then one final `strategy.exit()` just for the SL without any `qty`. That way it will close all the position.

```
if curStage == 1
    stopLevel := slPrice
    strategy.exit("LE-1", "Long", qty= 0.5 * strategy.position_size, limit = tpPrice, comment_profit = "Long TP", stop = slPrice, comment_loss = "Long SL")
    strategy.exit("LE-2", "Long", stop = slPrice, comment_loss = "Long SL")

    strategy.exit("SE-1", "Short", qty= 0.5 * strategy.position_size, limit = tpPrice, comment_profit = "Short TP", stop = slPrice, comment_loss = "Short SL")
    strategy.exit("SE-2", "Short", stop = slPrice, comment_loss = "Short SL")
```

Comment: Hi @vitruvius, I tried your code way, but it seems like the result is still incorrect. The results are shown in the above-updated part.